# .EXE file was created using pyinstaller does not work

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I made a simple GUI Application using Qt designer and PyQt5 just because I wanted to see if I can make an executable file off of a python script.

The script works fine in the text editor, but it
throws an error message when trying to open the `.exe` file.

[image: error]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import random


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(372, 301)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")

        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, 
        QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 4, 1, 1, 1)

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        font1 = QtGui.QFont()
        font1.setPointSize(8)
        font1.setBold(True)
        font1.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.random_value)

        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, 
        QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, 
        QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem2, 2, 1, 1, 1)

        spacerItem3 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, 
        QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem3, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 1, 1, 1, 1)


        spacerItem4 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, 
        QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem4, 1, 2, 1, 1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def random_value(self):
        self.label.setNum(random.randint(1,100))

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "                    RANDOM NUMBER"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is the GUI output when running the script in text editor:

[image: pic 1]

[image: pic 2]

Comment: may i know how many python instance is installed in your pc ?

Comment: please try once https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/

Comment: Reading the error message you are getting, it says pkgutil, which is used by PyQt5 when it does it's __init__, is missing. What this means is that when you created the exe that file was not included when it was made. Can you share the command you used when creating the exe from pyinstaller?

Comment: @Andew yes sure,  pyinstaller --onefile -w test.py

Comment: @JaydeepDevda python 3.10 and 3.9 i used the 3.9 version for this

Comment: so it could be you are running in text editor with 3.9 and building it with 3.10 or vice versa. please double check.

Comment: I recommend looking at the documentation here: https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html

Comment: You may want to use the `-p DIR, --paths DIR` section to tell pyinstaller what directories to include when building the exe and point it to the version of python you want to use for the installer.

Comment: Or install PyQt5 for both python 3.10 and python 3.9 and make sure that those files are available for both versions. It seems that pyinstaller may be using a version of python your not expecting.

Comment: @JaydeepDevda i tried auto-py-to-exe ,,but i got the same error again,

Comment: @JaydeepDevda i have uninstalled the python 3.10 version and also looked up which verion i'm using ,it was python 3.9.12

Comment: It may be because you have non-ASCII characters in your python PATH. What is the path to your  Python 3.9.12?

Comment: @Appli_boy C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.9

Comment: ok, for many cases, you need to avoid having a space in your path like you have in "Start Menu".

Comment: I changed 'start menu' to start_menu'
But still i get the same error massage @Appli_boy

Comment: I tried auto-py-to-exe. got the same error.